# RegEx to extract command line arguments - Java

Tags: java, regex, string, input, command-line-arguments

I know there is a lot out there.. But I couldn't figure out how to extract two parameters from `Scanner(System.in);`

```
commandline = scanner.readLine();
```

Two parameters are allowed:

First one can be one of `AHG` or the digits between 4 to 9.
The second parameters again between 4 to 9 OR any number.
It should handle all the scenarios:

```
   "      A    3  " //spaces before and after
   "A    3"         // spaces between the params
   "A    7     6"   // Unwanted 3rd parameter
   "  6  "          // Only one param with spaces.
```

So how to write Regex for this to extract the above?
I tried this one. `\\w\\s`. But this did not work. I am poor with RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseArguments(String argument){
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^\\s*([AHG4-9])\\s*(\\d)?\\s*$",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);

    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(argument);

    if (regexMatcher.find()) {

        ArrayList<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();

        arguments.add(regexMatcher.group(1));

        if(regexMatcher.group(2) != null)
        {
            arguments.add(regexMatcher.group(2));
        }

        return arguments;
    }

    return null;

}
```

Depending on your input:

It will print:

```
[A,3]
```

Above regex also enforce argument rules. e.g as you mention first parameter can be A,H,G or number between 4 and 9. 2nd argument any number and can be optional

Comment: I think you are trying to accomplish too much with a single statement. This makes your code difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you meant by difficult but tried not only parse arguments but also validate as per OP rules.

Comment: The regex you are using is probably hard to understand for most programmers who do not use complex regex regularly. Therefore I prefer to split the input first and then validate the arguments in a second step.

Comment: ah, not understanding regex is a totally different story :P

Comment: @FrankPuffer How is `whitespace; character class; whitespace; optional digit` complicated?

Comment: @KennethK.: Just my experience, 80% of developers don't understand regex at all, at most 5% understand complex ones with grouping etc. (I agree it's a bit sad.)

Answer (score 3):

Use this on the string returned by `readLine()`:

```
String [] arguments = commandLine.split( "\\s+" );
```

The `\\s+` stands for at least one whitespace character as separator.

Then check how many elements the array has.

Fimally check the formats of the two arguments

1. `arguments[0].matches("\\s*[AHG4-9]");`
2. `arguments[1].matches("\\d");`

Comment: How do I ignore whitespace and extract only the arguments?

Comment: @KevinRave: That's what `commandLine.split( "\\s+" );` should do.